# Can I set a ViewBag property in an ASP.NET view?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have error in this code:

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Settings", new { ViewBag.IsView = true })" class="btn">View</a>
```

Can I set in `ViewBag.IsView` property `true`?

`ViewBag.IsView` is declared just in this scope nowhere else.

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Error 23 Invalid anonymous type member declarator. Anonymous type members must be declared with a member assignment, simple name or member access.

Comment: You can't set ViewBag property in View. You can set this at controller and access from View.

Comment: You are declaring an anynonymous type with new {...}. A property name can't contain a dot (.). But looking at the comments above mine, it looks like you are trying to achieve something entirely different here.

Comment: You could, from your view, call an action method that would set the ViewBag but you would not see the result as the ViewBag value would only be visible for the next HTTP request

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can simply set as:

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Settings", new { IsView = true })" class="btn">View</a>
```

and in your `Settings` action, get it as below through parameter:

```
public ActionResult Settings (bool IsView)
{
  ....
}
```

No need to forcefully use `ViewBag` here